# How to set up varnish on different server?

Tags: magento, varnish, varnish-vcl

I'd like to know how to use varnish to cache website that is in different server?

I have my website that uses Magento CE, I have already installed turpentine extension and I have different dedicated server. I successfully installed varnish on dedicated server, how to configure varnish to tell that I need to cache website that's in different server, where should insert server ip, I only found varnish tutorials where it's installed in the same server.

Answer (score 0):

You just specify within your

```
backend .. {
```

section the ip address + port of your 2nd server.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a backend that points at your webservers ip or domainname.
Here a example with provided healtcheck.

```
probe healthcheck_webserver {
    .url = "/";
    .interval = 5s;
    .timeout = 1s;
    .window = 5;
    .threshold = 3;
    .expected_response = 200;
}

backend webserver {
   .host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
   .port = "THEPORTTHATAPACHELISTENSTO";
   .probe =  healthcheck_webserver;
}
```

And ofcourse dont forget to use this backend in sub vcl_recv:

```
if (req.http.host ~ "yourdomain.com") 
{
    set req.backend = webserver;
}
```