# Install Magento 2 and Varnish Cache on different server

Tags: varnish, magento-2.0, varnish-4

I have 2 servers, one which has magento 2 installed (ip - 129.89.188.244 port 80) and Varnish on another (ip - 129.89.188.245 port 80)

My Varnish Configuration:

File /etc/default/varnish:-

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T 127.0.0.1:6082 \
             -b 129.89.188.244:80 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,256m"
```

netstat -tulpn :-

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1288/sshd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11115/varnishd  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11115/varnishd  
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1288/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      11115/varnishd
```

/etc/varnish/default.vcl : -

```
# VCL version 5.0 is not supported so it should be 4.0 even though actually used Varnish version is 5
vcl 4.0;

import std;
# The minimal Varnish version is 5.0
# For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'X-Forwarded-Proto: https'

backend default {
    .host = "129.89.188.244";
    .port = "80";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "/pub/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}

acl purge {
    "129.89.188.245";
    "127.0.0.1";
    "localhost";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
        }
        # To use the X-Pool header for purging varnish during automated deployments, make sure the X-Pool header
        # has been added to the response in your backend server config. This is used, for example, by the
        # capistrano-magento2 gem for purging old content from varnish during it's deploy routine.
        if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
            return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));
        }
        if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        }
        if (req.http.X-Pool) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
        }
        return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
          /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
          return (pipe);
    }

    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass shopping cart, checkout and search requests
    if (req.url ~ "/checkout" || req.url ~ "/catalogsearch") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass health check requests
    if (req.url ~ "/pub/health_check.php") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Set initial grace period usage status
    set req.http.grace = "none";

    # normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");

    # collect all cookies
    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);

    # Compression filter. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/FAQ/Compression
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
            # No point in compressing these
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unkown algorithm
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    # Remove Google gclid parameters to minimize the cache objects
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+$",""); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA"
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+&","?"); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA&foo=bar"
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"&gclid=[^&]+",""); # strips when QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA" or QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA&bar=baz"

    # Static files caching
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        # Static files should not be cached by default
        return (pass);

        # But if you use a few locales and don't use CDN you can enable caching static files by commenting previous line (#return (pass);) and uncommenting next 3 lines
        #unset req.http.Https;
        #unset req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto;
        #unset req.http.Cookie;
    }

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }

    # For multi site configurations to not cache each other's content
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }

    # To make sure http users don't see ssl warning
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
    }

}

sub vcl_backend_response {

    set beresp.grace = 3d;

    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }

    # cache only successfully responses and 404s
    if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);
    } elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
        return (deliver);
    }

    # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
    # images, css and js are cacheable by default so we have to remove cookie also
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }

   # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass
   if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
       beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
       (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
       beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store") ||
       beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        # Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
            set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
        } else {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
        }
    } else {
        unset resp.http.Age;
    }

    # Not letting browser to cache non-static files.
    if (resp.http.Cache-Control !~ "private" && req.url !~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
        set resp.http.Expires = "-1";
        set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
    }

    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
    unset resp.http.Server;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Via;
    unset resp.http.Link;
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
        # Hit within TTL period
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        if (obj.ttl + 300s > 0s) {
            # Hit after TTL expiration, but within grace period
            set req.http.grace = "normal (healthy server)";
            return (deliver);
        } else {
            # Hit after TTL and grace expiration
            return (miss);
        }
    } else {
        # server is not healthy, retrieve from cache
        set req.http.grace = "unlimited (unhealthy server)";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

Now the issue is, when I open the URL `129.89.188.244` , magento opens but it's not getting cached in varnish. But when I call  varnish URL `129.89.188.245`, it will redirect to my magento url `129.89.188.244`. In my varnish log, it shows that the page is cached already but magento is not getting served from that varnish cache.

Comment: I am not sure but this could be related [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843279/how-to-set-up-varnish-on-different-server)

Comment: Nope, his backend points to the correct host - see: backend default {
    .host = "129.89.188.244"; in his listed configuration file.

Comment: Can you post 2 screenshots of the requested cachable resources in the web/dev console, of 2  consecutive requests made from the same browser against the Varnish URL? It would be best if you can clear the Varnish cache before that.

Comment: When you are testing this - have you set magento into dev mode? magento deploy:mode:set

Comment: Yes i have set dev mod in my magento

Comment: @DhavalBhavsar, can you please add the output of `curl -v http://129.89.188.245` to your question?

Answer (score 3):

In order for the cache to work, your requests always have to go through the proxy/cache (`Varnish`).

`Varnish` evaluates your requests and decides if the request is already cached (then returns it from the cache) or not - then it will redirect it to `Magento` and cache the response, before returning it to the client.

That's how most caches work. You can read in detail how `Varnish` cache mechanism works [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/use-varnish-cache-how.html).

If you want to hit your cache, you always have to go through `Varnish` `(129.89.188.245:80)`.

Consider this diagram form the official [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html):

[image]

Comment: so you mean that i need to call varnish server that's right but varnish redirect to magento server in these case what i need to do?

Comment: Yes you need to call the Varnish server, not calling the Magento server directly. I think your setup is correct. You can verify if you're getting back cached results following the verification steps as described here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-final.html

Comment: But i have one question if i will call varnish server but it will redirect magento then after that i click on any link in my e-commerce cart it's not call varnish so for that what i need to do?

Comment: You should fix magento base url and clear cache by the commands below:
```
bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://varnish.host/"
bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url-secure="https://varnish.host/"
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: how can I check the diagram working fine on my server?

Answer (score 0):

this is the expected behaviour.
Varnish sits in front of you Magento server and if you ping your Magento server bypassing Varnish, opening 129.89.188.244, then Magento will send you a response without involving Varnish, while if you ping varnish, Varnish will then call Magento and cache. The other way around is not possible and makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
This solution worked for me. To configure Varnish and Magento on a different server.

Varnish server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 80

Magento server: yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy port 80

Changes need to be made on the varnish server: 

 1. login to varnish server
 2. go to file /etc/varnish/default.vcl
 3. under the "backend default" update

    .host = "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy";//(use Magento server IP for better network)
    .port = "80";//(Magento web server port) 
 4. Restart the Varnish (systemctl restart varnish)

Note: Kindly use the default VCL that is generated during the varnish installation and don't update it with Magento generated VCL for varnish ( available from Magento Admin)

Changes need to be made on the Magento server:
1. Log in to the Magento server
2. Go to the env.php file located in the app/etc directory
3. Update the values in     'http_cache_hosts' => [
        [
            'host' => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', //(varnish server public ip)
            'port' => '80' // ( varnish server port)
        ]
    ]
Now update your base URL's on the core_config_data table to your varnish public  Ip (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/)
flush the Magento caches ( bin/magento ca:fl)
```